# Regexp: some questions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**Python 3**

```
text = "(CNN)Meaalofa Te'o -- Buemi. Canberra,"

def discard_punctuation(text):
    regex = '\W*^\s^\d*-'
    return re.sub(regex, "", text)

def handle_text(text):
    text_without_punctuation = discard_punctuation(text)
    words_array = text_without_punctuation.split()
    pass // Breakpoint

handle_text(text)
```

From an arbitrary text **I want to select words only.** Investigating the problem, I have discovered that sometimes a hyphen is inside a word. Or a number may be as well (9-year-old, canyon-like).

My regex is regex = '\W*^\s^\d*-'.

Take all non-alphanumeric character; exclude all whitespace charactes, which are necessary for split method; exclude all numbers that are not followed by a hyphen.

I should also exclude hyphens that are not in words.

The result is:
: ['(CNN)Meaalofa', "Te'o", '--', 'Buemi.', 'Canberra,']

The documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

```
\W
Matches any non-alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class [^a-zA-Z0-9_].
```

I thought that points, commas, hyphen, brackets and apostrophe should match \W.

Questions:
**1. I can't understand why: brackets, points and commas, and apostrophe are still present.**

2. I would say that I excluded the apostrophe. I need it, and it is present in the result, it is Ok. But I can't catch how it occurred there. **Could you help me understand how apostrophe happened to occur in the result.**
3. **Well, "--" is definitely an error here. How to cope?**
4. Could you, please, suggest me a better regexp.

Comment: What are the questions?

Comment: i highly recommend to use debuggex.com to validate how regex works.

Comment: Try `r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*'`.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, like this: return re.findall(regex, text)? The result will be <class 'list'>: ['', 'CNN', '', 'Meaalofa', '', '', 'Te', '', 'o', '', '', '', '', 'Buemi', '', '', 'Canberra', '', '']. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: See `print(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[-'][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*", text))` - https://ideone.com/OCLhbZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your rather vague definition of a "word", you could come up with:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\s*(\S+)\s*')

string = """(CNN)Meaalofa Te'o -- Buemi. Canberra,"""
words = rx.findall(string)
print(words)
# ['(CNN)Meaalofa', "Te'o", '--', 'Buemi.', 'Canberra,']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/WB9QmL) and on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zH2bQ6/1). You might redefine what a "word" is.

Comment: I need some time to think. Looks promising.

Comment: I think the `\s*` are totally redundant here, r'\S+' is enough with this approach. `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace symbols, so, it will also match punctuation and all other symbols (`Matt#@$#%`).